# Need help adding fields using MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using a MySQL DB to manage employees. I maintain the DB in PHPMyAdmin. I want to add 70 new fields into a table by using SQL. I thought this would work. Can you tell me why it doesn't

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dist` (

  `e_employee1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_name1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_title1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_phone1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_ext1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_phone21` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_email1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_employee2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_name2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_title2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_phone2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_ext2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_phone22` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_email12` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_employee3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_name3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_title3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_phone3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_ext3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_phone23` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_email3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_employee4` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_name4` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_title4` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_phone4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_ext4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_phone24` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_email4` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_employee5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_name5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_title5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_phone5` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_ext5` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_phone25` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_email5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_employee6` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_name6` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_title6` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_phone6` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_ext6` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_phone26` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_email6` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_employee7` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_name7` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_title7` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_phone7` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_ext7` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_phone27` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_email7` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_employee8` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_name8` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_title8` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_phone8` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_ext8` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_phone28` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_email8` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_employee9` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_name9` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_title9` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_phone9` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_ext9` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_phone29` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_email9` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_employee10` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_name10` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_title10` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `e_phone10` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_ext10` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_phone210` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_email10` varchar(255) NOT NULL,


  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;
```

Comment: @Mike - what, if any, errors are you getting?

Comment: I can't understand your DB design. Are you planning to create a column group for each new employee?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS `dist` ( `e_employee1` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `e_name1` va' at line 1

Comment: No I have many businesses with different employee contact. these are fields for each business

Comment: @Alvaro G. Vicario is asking why employees 1-10 aren't in a separate `employees` table that's linked to companies by ID. Basic MySQL database design.

Comment: because eah business has 1-10 employees. Is there an issue with having 80+ fields?

Comment: There's an issue with this sort of structure for employees. It makes queries more difficult than they'd be with joins, it presents annoyances when an employee leaves a company, and it's a pain when you get a new company that has 11 employees.

Comment: @ceejayoz, Thats not a concern. There wont ever be a company that needs 10 employees. There also wont be any queries. It's just for reference. Please help me learn to added the fields without having to do it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `CREATE TABLE`. You should be using `ALTER TABLE` if you want to **add** fields. PHPMyAdmin should be showing you an error indicating that the table already exists.

Comment: The error is

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS `dist` ( `e_employee1` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `e_name1` va' at line 1

Comment: @Mike - The syntax error doesn't really matter. You cannot alter an existing table with `CREATE TABLE`. Period.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin shows you the SQL it used to add fields to a table. Add a field via the UI and see what its query looks like.